# Как изменить количество повторений boot logo Raspberry?

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Есть Raspberry Pi 3, есть Rasbian, есть boot logo при загрузке системы (появляется в левом верхнем углу четыре малинки), компилирую ядро Raspbian. Как поменять изображение я понял, но где изменить код на количество изображений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге обошелся увеличением изображения.